# Instantiating an object from bean using constructor args and refs

Tags: java, spring

I've a class which takes in 2 Object Injections. 1 of them is to be injected through other bean ref whereas the other injected based on bean call. I want to instantiate an object using spring. How can I do this ?

I tried doing this:

MyBean Class:

```
class MyBean{
    Injection1 ijn1;
    MyBean(Injection1 ijn1,Injection2 ijn2){
      this.ijn1=ijn1;
      this.ijn2=ijn2;
    }
}
```

Beans.xml

```
<bean name="myBean" class="MyBean" scope="prototype">
    <constructor-arg>
        <null />
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg>
        <ref bean="injection2" />
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>


<bean name="injection2" class="Injection2">
</bean>
```

Application Code:

```
MyBean getMyBean(Injection ijn1) {
    return (MyBean)context.getBean("myBean", new Object[] { ijn1 })
}
```

But this doesn't works.

Any tips ?

Comment: This usage is strange, if you need a repository of beans you should use a map, and `getMyBean` become a map lookup. Also your `getBean()` usage is strange, you should read the javadoc of `getBean()`

Comment: Ooops corrected the getBean usage. 
I don't want to create a repository of bean, ijn1 would be different for every request and hence need to create a new bean object for every type. I want MyBean to be stateful and aware of ijn1. May be you won't want to read ijn1 as injection and would like to read it as data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code doesn't work because spring looks for a `MyBean`'s constructor like `MyBean(Injection1 ijn1)`; you have to pass `injection2` in this way.

```
MyBean getMyBean(Injection ijn1) {
    return (MyBean)context.getBean("myBean", new Object[] { ijn1, context.getBean("injection2") })
}
```

If you want to use your code another way is to have partial inject in this way:

```
class MyBean{
    Injection1 ijn1;
    Injection2 ijn2;
    MyBean(Injection1 ijn1){
      this.ijn1=ijn1;
    }

    public void setIjn2(Injection2 ijn2I ) {
      this.ijn2 = ijn2;
    }
}
```

and in xml

```
<bean name="myBean" class="MyBean" scope="prototype">
  <property name="inj2" ref="injection2" />
</bean>


<bean name="injection2" class="Injection2">
</bean>
```

Comment: Would  return (MyBean)context.getBean("myBean", new Object[] { ijn1 }) work in another case you mentioned ?

Comment: yes. but you have to change MyBean ctor and bean.xml as I wrote in second case