# How to Instantiate spring bean with in a method with runtime constructor arguments?

Tags: spring, inversion-of-control

I need to instantiate a bean ( EmployeeSaver) with in a method with parameter coming in  dynamically. I can't use constructor setter for these values are not populated at config time.

Sample code:

```
class MyEmployeeBean{
    public void   saveEmployeeDetail (Employee employee , EmployeeHistory hist   ){
        EmployeeDetail detail = hist.getDetail();
        EmployeeSaver eSave = new EmployeeSaver(employee, detail)
        saver.saveEmployee();
    }
}

class EmployeeSaver {

    private Employee empl;
    private EmployeeDetail detail;

    public EmployeeSaver(Employee emp, EmployeeDetail det){

        empl = emp;
        detail = det;
    }

    public void saveEmployee(){
        // code to same the guy...
    }

}
```

As MyEmployeeSaver class don't have default constructor so it's throwing runtime exception.  I am unsable to use following config as employeeDetail is not know until I do hist.getDetail() !

```
<bean id="mySaverBean" class="come.saver.EmployeeSaver">
    <constructor-arg name="empl" ref="employee" />
    <constructor-arg name="hist" ref = "employeeHistory" />
</bean>
```

How to instantiate employeeSaverBean with constructor arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this directly with Spring configuration, but using `ApplicationContext.getBean(String beanName,Object...args)` like described in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18494522/instantiating-an-object-from-bean-using-constructor-args-and-refs/18494904#18494904).
`MyEmployeeBean` must implements [`ApplicationContextAware`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContextAware.html) to access Spring's context

```
class MyEmployeeBean implements ApplicationContextAware {
  ApplicationContext applicationContext;

  void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
    this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
  }

  public void   saveEmployeeDetail (Employee employee , EmployeeHistory hist   ){
        EmployeeDetail detail = hist.getDetail();
        EmployeeSaver eSave = (EmployeeSaver)this.applicationContextnew.getBean("mySaverBean", employee, detail);
        saver.saveEmployee();
    }
}
```

and in beans.xml

```
<bean id="mySaverBean" class="come.saver.EmployeeSaver" scope="prototype" />
```

Remeber to addo `scope="prototype"` to let Spring create a new instance at every request.